# Dynamically Added Dropdown not applying jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dynamic, dropdown

I am using bootstrap and jquery in my react project. I have a button when clicked should change to a dropdown field. The dropdown works if I put it normally, but once I call it dynamically it no longer works. Here's my code:

When I use it like this; it works

```
<div className="profile-otr">
                  <a className="profile-inr click-open3">
                    <img
                      className="creator"
                      src="../assets/img/favicon-32.png"
                      alt="creator"
                    />
                    <p className="price body-sb">{ellipseAddress(address)}</p>
                  </a>
                  <div className="icon-hover-2 click-event3">
                    <h5 className="heading heading-h5">The Lucky Being</h5>
                    <div className="copy-icon-otr">
                      <p className="desc body-s">{ellipseAddress(address)}</p>
                      <svg
                        className="copy-icon"
                        width="18"
                        height="18"
                        fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M12.636 12.636H15a2 2 0 002-2V3a2 2 0 00-2-2H7.364a2 2 0 00-2 2v2.364"
                          stroke="#CFCFCF"
                          stroke-width="2"
                          stroke-linecap="round"
                          stroke-linejoin="round"
                        />
                        <path
                          d="M10.636 5.364H3a2 2 0 00-2 2V15a2 2 0 002 2h7.636a2 2 0 002-2V7.364a2 2 0 00-2-2z"
                          stroke="#CFCFCF"
                          stroke-width="2"
                          stroke-linecap="round"
                          stroke-linejoin="round"
                        />
                      </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div className="box-otr">
                      <div className="img-otr">
                        <img
                          className="img-eht"
                          src="../assets/img/ethereum.png"
                          alt="img"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="price-otr">
                        <p className="desc body-s">Current Balance</p>
                        <h5 className="heading heading-h5">3.067 ETH</h5>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul className="link-profile-otr">
                      <li className="link-profile-inr">
                        <span className="circle-hover"></span>
                        <a href="#" className="profile body-sb">
                          My Profile
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="link-profile-inr">
                        <span className="circle-hover"></span>
                        <a href="#" className="profile body-sb">
                          My Items
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="link-profile-inr">
                        <span className="circle-hover"></span>
                        <a href="#" className="profile body-sb">
                          Manage Funds
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="link-profile-inr">
                        <span className="circle-hover"></span>
                        <a href="#" className="profile body-sb">
                          Disconnect
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

But when I set a conditional statement, like this; It doesnt work anymore

```
{!address ? (
                <div className="action-otr">
                  <a onClick={connect} className="btn-fill btn-wallet">
                    Connect Wallet
                  </a>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="profile-otr">
                  <a className="profile-inr click-open3">
                    <img
                      className="creator"
                      src="../assets/img/favicon-32.png"
                      alt="creator"
                    />
                    <p className="price body-sb">{ellipseAddress(address)}</p>
                  </a>
                  <div className="icon-hover-2 click-event3">
                    <h5 className="heading heading-h5">The Lucky Being</h5>
                    <div className="copy-icon-otr">
                      <p className="desc body-s">{ellipseAddress(address)}</p>
                      <svg
                        className="copy-icon"
                        width="18"
                        height="18"
                        fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M12.636 12.636H15a2 2 0 002-2V3a2 2 0 00-2-2H7.364a2 2 0 00-2 2v2.364"
                          stroke="#CFCFCF"
                          stroke-width="2"
                          stroke-linecap="round"
                          stroke-linejoin="round"
                        />
                        <path
                          d="M10.636 5.364H3a2 2 0 00-2 2V15a2 2 0 002 2h7.636a2 2 0 002-2V7.364a2 2 0 00-2-2z"
                          stroke="#CFCFCF"
                          stroke-width="2"
                          stroke-linecap="round"
                          stroke-linejoin="round"
                        />
                      </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div className="box-otr">
                      <div className="img-otr">
                        <img
                          className="img-eht"
                          src="../assets/img/ethereum.png"
                          alt="img"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="price-otr">
                        <p className="desc body-s">Current Balance</p>
                        <h5 className="heading heading-h5">3.067 ETH</h5>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul className="link-profile-otr">
                      <li className="link-profile-inr">
                        <span className="circle-hover"></span>
                        <a href="#" className="profile body-sb">
                          My Profile
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="link-profile-inr">
                        <span className="circle-hover"></span>
                        <a href="#" className="profile body-sb">
                          My Items
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="link-profile-inr">
                        <span className="circle-hover"></span>
                        <a href="#" className="profile body-sb">
                          Manage Funds
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="link-profile-inr">
                        <span className="circle-hover"></span>
                        <a href="#" className="profile body-sb">
                          Disconnect
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".click-open3").click(function () {
    $(".click-event3").toggleClass("displayblock");
    $(".click-event2").removeClass("displayblock");
    $(".click-event1").removeClass("displayblock");
  });
  $(".click-open2").click(function () {
    $(".click-event2").toggleClass("displayblock");
    $(".click-event3").removeClass("displayblock");
    $(".click-event1").removeClass("displayblock");
  });
  $(".click-open1").click(function () {
    $(".click-event1").toggleClass("displayblock");
    $(".click-event2").removeClass("displayblock");
    $(".click-event3").removeClass("displayblock");
  });
  $(".burger-click").click(function () {
    $(".click-event1").removeClass("displayblock");
    $(".click-event2").removeClass("displayblock");
    $(".click-event3").removeClass("displayblock");
  });
});
```

I have searched online and read different articles and stack overflow solutions but none seem to work and I'm stuck need help please.

Comment: search "how to add events on dynamically added elements"

Comment: also, this code be a lot cleaner

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I have already searched that, and how do you mean cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeToggle` in `jQuery` instead of toggle `class`

```js
    $("[class^='.click-'], .burger-click").click(function() {
        $(YOUR_ELEMENT).fadeToggle();
    });
```